# Why are some JavaScript functions given conjugated names and not others?

Tags: javascript

As a non-english developer, I often wonder why some javascript functions take a "s" and others don't.

Example:

```
Array.includes()
Element.contains()
```

I could figure it's because they are verbs conjugated in the third person. But in that case, why don't the following conjugate?

```
Array.reduce()
Array.find()
Array.map()
```

Is there some rule I'm unaware of, or is it just a question of what sounds better for the developer who first writes a library?

Comment: `includes()` is talking about a feature of the array. "This array includes the string `'hello world'`". It returns a boolean, which is a response to the statement. `reduce()` and `map()` are actions - you are commanding the array, "hey! map yourself!".

Comment: Because of english grammar. `includes()` is something the array "does"  ie, the array "does include" a value. Whereas with `find()` or `reduce()` it's something you do *with/to*  the array.

Comment: `includes()` and `contains()` both return `boolean` values indicating [a _present simple tense_ adjective](https://cooljugator.com/en/include) state of the subject, hence the "s" suffix, but `reduce()` and `find()` are "do-something" functions, hence they have non-conjugated verbs for names. Non-`boolean` returning methods and properties likely wouldn't be so-named. I don't exactly know why, though... [English grammar is _weird_](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL96C35uN7xGLDEnHuhD7CTZES3KXFnwm0).

Comment: A note. If  `Array.prototype` had a method called `include()`, it would be doing some sort of action on the array, likely taking in a value and including it in the array somehow. Think of it like speaking - ex. "`foo` includes the property `'bar'`" -> `foo.includes('bar')`. and a command: "Push `'bar'` to `foo` right now!" -> `foo.push('bar')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone who was an English teacher, I'll firstly say that the main reason this is the case is because English kinda *sucks*. The grammar is weird, and no matter how many rules you memorize, you'll never speak it absolutely perfectly. Even us native speakers struggle with grammar on a daily basis.

To answer your question thoroughly:

1. Methods such as `includes()` and `contains()` are statements that **describe** the array/value and return a "yes" or a "no" (a `true` or `false`) statement.

**English:**

> My shopping list **includes** bacon. Is this true?

**JavaScript:**

```
const includesBacon = shoppingList.includes('bacon');

console.log(includesBacon); // -> boolean
```

2. Methods such as `reduce()` and `map()` perform an **action** on the array/value. You are literally commanding the array to do something to itself.

**English:**

> **Please map** out a new shopping list based on the old, but all bacon. Now!

**JavaScript:**

```
shoppingList.map(() => 'bacon')
```